# Format string to number with minimum length in lua

Tags: lua

For example I need number with minimum 3 digit

```
"512" --> 512
"24"  --> 24.0
"5"   --> 5.00
```

One option is write small function. Using answers here for my case it will be something like this

```
function f(value, w)    
    local p = math.ceil(math.log10(value))
    local prec = value <= 1 and w - 1 or p > w and 0 or w - p
    return string.format('%.' .. prec .. 'f', value)
end

print(f(12, 3))
```

But may be it is possible just using string.format() or any other simple way?

Comment: `str=(str..'\0.000'):gsub('(%..-)%.','%1'):gsub('%d','%0\0',3):match'.*%z':gsub('%z','')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Maximum you can reach - specify floating point precision or digit number, but you can't force output to be like your example. Lua uses C like printf with few limitations [reference](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.format). Look here for full specifiers list [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/). Remember unsupported ones.

Writing a function would be the best and only solution, especially as your task looks strange, as it doesn't count decimal dot.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it seems this case beyond the string.format power. Thanks to @Schollii, this is my current variant

```
function f(value, w)    
    local p = math.ceil(math.log10(value))
    local prec = value <= 1 and w - 1 or p > w and 0 or w - p
    return string.format('%.' .. prec .. 'f', value)
end

print(f(12, 3))
```

Comment: Nice. I think, you can edit your post and include your solution there.

Comment: @Seagull, excuse me, I'm new here and not good in Q&A formatting. Should I delete this answer after editing start post?

Comment: Just add your solution in question. It will help future readers find it, and see what have you done.

Answer (score 1):

There is no format code specifically for this since `string.format` uses `printf` minus a few codes (like `*` which would hace simplified the solution I give below). So you have to implement yourself, for example:

```
function f(num, w)
    -- get number of digits before decimal
    local intWidth = math.ceil(math.log10(num))
    -- if intWidth > w then ... end -- may need this
    local fmt='%'..w..'.' .. (w-intWidth) .. 'f'
    return string.format(fmt, num)
end

print(f(12, 4))
print(f(12, 3))
print(f(12, 2))

print(f(512, 3))
print(f(24, 3))
print(f(5, 3))
```

You should probably handle case where integer part doesn't fit in field width given (return ceil or floor?).